# Sketch of 1-norm and ∞-norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Why do we say a sketch of unit **ball** of Norms ||.||<sub>1</sub> and ||.||<sub>∞</sub>?? Actually as seen in sketch it is a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **ball** because for the Euclidean norm $||\cdot||_2$ it is a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The name is used by extension to other norms.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are correct.

Another way to understand the use of the word "ball" is to think from the point of view of someone living in the space. For them the distance from the origin to the edge of the unit ball is $1$ in any direction, so "ball" is a good name for the set. For those two norms the unit ball looks like a square only when you view it from outside, with Euclidean geometry instead of its intrinsic geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The term "unit-ball" is widely used to indicate the set of elements (in any normed space) whose norm is at most $1$.